# tsc --declaration: how to hide private methods and attributes?

Tags: typescript, tsc

Running `tsc` with `--declaration` option generates the `.d.ts` file with all the declaration, private included.

Is there a way to produce a `.d.ts` file with only exported types and, for classes, only public methods and attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible.

Typescript keeps privates in generated .d.ts files to support further inheritance.

Because there is no such thing as 'private' in JS, declaring a type that derives from a d.ts type with stripped out privates could cause problems if you accidentally will have a name collision in your child class. That will be very difficult to find and fix.

Comment: You confirmed my suspect

Comment: Not not possible anymore - TS 3.8+ supports true private properties and respects the private status of these fields. But the scope is limited to those true private properties - `private` and `/** @private */` marked properties are emitted as usual.